# Mongoose edit an object in an array or add it to the array if it doesn't exist by a certain property

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a Schema that looks like this:

```
var RoomSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    venueId: { type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    name: {
        type: String
    },
    special: [{
            date: {type: Date},
            pricing: {
                isOpen: { type: Boolean },
                openTime: { type: String }
            }
        }]
});
```

and I want to push a new object onto the "special" array, unless the "date" already exists in the array.  I know upsert will add a new object if it doesn't exist, but how can I search if the object exists only by the date property and not the entirety of the object?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the new special object looks something like this:

```
var newSpecial = {
    date: new Date(2016, 5, 1);
    pricing: {
        isOpen: true,
        openTime: '8:00am'
    }
};
```

And you know the venue id:

```
var venueId = 1234;
```

Try this:

```
Room.findOne({venueId: venueId, 'special.date': newSpecial.date})
    .exec(function(err, roomDoc) {
        if (err) { ... }

        // update special if it exists
        if (roomDoc) { 
            Room.update(
                {venueId: venueId},
                {$set: {'special.$.pricing': newSpecial.pricing}} 
                function(err) { ... }
            );
        }

        // add special if it doesn't exist
        else {
            Room.update(
                {venueId: venueId}, 
                {$push: {special: newSpecial}}, 
                function(err) { ... }
            );
        }
    });
```

The key here is using `'special.date'` as the key in your query object, and using the [positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) `'special.$.pricing'` to update the correct special in the array if it exists.

Comment: this does half of what I want, but if the query finds a roomDoc, how can I update the object in the array that has the same date as the query?

Comment: I added some logic for updating the existing special if it exists using mongodb's positional operator. Give it a try.